# C# game of chance

Tags: c#, probability

I am new to C#.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to create a game of chance system here.

Basically this is how it is:

**My question:** How do I do to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to generate a random number and randomly pick an item from a list, where each item in the list has a weighted chance of being picked.  Probably the simplest thing to do would be to sum up the "chances" and randomize between 0 and sum(chance), then pick the item that falls on that number.  Does that sound right?

Comment: The `Random` class has a method `Next(int MaxValue)` that might help you. Do a little search on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example code has a hard bug: you've written `150/208` and `190/209`. This is an integer division, and both result in **zero**. You should have written: `150.0/208` and `190.0/209` to instruct the compiler to divide them as double's not integers.

Edit:
Assuming the system's RNG is flat and that your table is as follows:

```
[item]    [amount]
0        3 000 000
25       1 500 000
50       2 000 000
75       300 000
100      10 000
150      10 000    (no typo)
  sum  = 6820000
```

Then your randomizer can look like:

```
int randomItemNumber = Random.Next(6820000); // 0..6819999
if(randomItemNumber < 3000000)
    Console.WriteLine("Aah, you've won the Item type #0\n");
else if(randomItemNumber < 3000000+1500000)
    Console.WriteLine("Aah, you've won the Item type #1\n");
else if(randomItemNumber < 3000000+1500000+2000000)
    Console.WriteLine("Aah, you've won the Item type #2\n");
else if(randomItemNumber < 3000000+1500000+2000000+300000)
    Console.WriteLine("Aah, you've won the Item type #3\n");
else if(randomItemNumber < 3000000+1500000+2000000+300000+10000)
    Console.WriteLine("Aah, you've won the Item type #4\n");
else if(randomItemNumber < 3000000+1500000+2000000+300000+10000+10000)
    Console.WriteLine("Aah, you've won the Item type #5\n");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Oops, somehow you won nothing, the code is broken!\n");
```

The idea is that you put all the items in a looong line, one after another, but you keep them in their groups. So, at start there's three milion of the first kind, then a milion-and-half of the second type and so on. There are in total 6820000 items in the line. Now you randomly pick a number from 1 to 6820000 (or from 0 to 6819999) and use it as the NUMBER of an element in the LINE.

As the items are present in the line with their correct statistical distribution, then if the randomization 1-6820000 was FLAT, then the resulting 'lottery' will have distribution exactly as you you wanted.

The only trick left to explain, is how to guess what item was picked. This is why we kept the items in groups. The first part of 3000000 items is the first type, so if the number was less than 3000000 then we hit the first type. If more than that, but lower than the next 1500000 (lower than 4500000) then the second type is hit.. and so on.

Comment: I have done that and that code works now. Thanks. But do you think it is enough for what I am trying to do? I am not good with statistics so much.

Comment: You are on a good way. I've added a long explanation on how the 'generator with tabular distribution' works. Please re-read my post.

Comment: This seems to work very well. I have experimented with it for a while. But I wonder about a few things, sorry if it's too many questions.

**1**- What do you mean by flat randomization?

**2**- Does it matter if eventually all the amounts end up to 100%? 

**3**- Why do we not need to use any percentage chance? Does it matter if we don't?

**4**- Is there anyway I can test this code if I already know probability? For example chance of getting X is 80%, so I run this code in a loop for 50 times and then see if it works. For example then X should be displayed around 80% times in the loop, or?

Comment: Flat randomization is "the opposite" of what you are trying to do now. "Flat" means that each kind of the response from a random generator is equally probable. If you'd chart a probability-versus-itemtype you'd get a flat line. I've said about the system RNG being flat - our attempt relies on the system RNG to generate us a numbers from 1 to N. What would be if the distribution of that system RNG was not fair, i.e. what if it would generate "555" ten times too often? Our rnd algo would be wrong, because one of the item types would be noticeably favored and we would have to compensate for that.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Look at my example, I've there an "oops" case. The threshold values in the if-elses assume that everything adds up to 6820000. If your item weights does not add up to the full 6820000 but, i.e. to 5000000 (~73%), then ~27% of times the generator would "fail" and would not return an item at all. However, on the rest of the cases (73% of times) it would succeed and would work properly. This means that instead of a distro of, i.e. [10%,30%,5%,25%,15%,15%] you'd actually get a [7.3%,21.9%,3.65%,18.25%,10.95%,10.95%], as everything would be down times 0.73%.

Comment: Still, if the randomizer "hit the items", then the distribution of item types among items hits would be OK. It's just adding a "margin" of not hitting at all, what of course offsets all item-hitting probabilities. On the other hand, if your items would add up to a value higher than that 6820000 it would be worse: the items on the "end of the line" would simply never be hit, as the RNG's max value was set to 6820000 by us. That damages the distribution in a way hard to describe. It'd just handicap, oh, I found the word: it would TRIM the probability of all types that OVERFLOWn the limit.

Comment: The percentages - it is tricky and picky! Say percentages, you mean 12.3345% etc? Look, there are fractions! How fractions are treated by the CPU? Arithmetics on them are **not** exact! You can accidentially make a mistake in adding up, the compiler may round it off in some surprising manner, etc - and it would all affect the distribution. That would be tiny distortions, but, for example, if having 3 types of count 10000 and 4th of a single item - with calculations on floats/doubles you could actually never hit that one mostly prized item, because .. its small fraction would get dropped.

Comment: While you could calculate on the doubles and take care of proper rounding - by doing all maths on integers you are automatically sure that this problem will not arise. Well, unless the integer overflows, so a uint64 (unsigned long) would probably be a better choice. Please not that This is a very picky and uber-correct approach. If you do not need an exact 100% statistically correct results, you may just as well do the maths on doubles. But if you do, then remember about the delicate fractions.

Comment: A good RNG generates the numbers independently of each other. Actually, in computer science it is hyper hard to achieve. There is almost always some history or some environment that affects and "offsets" the next run, but everyone tries to minimize it to neglible or undetectable margins. If you run it and got a "45" it does not **not mean** that the next number must be "17". Thus, running the test 50 times will get you 31 hits. or 49 hits. or **even one or none** hits at all, depending on your luck (and bugs in the code).

Comment: However, the expected amount is 40 and the actual value should oscillate around that. If the RNG is good, then the more runs you perform, the closer the statistic will be to the estimate. If you run it infinitely times, you may consider to be sure that the stats will be exactly equal. But any finite number of runs is allowed to be off. Sadly, allowed to be off by a unspecified amount, due to the statistical premise that this was very (un)lucky series of runs and probably the next series of runs ill be less off... I hope I;ve managed to explain the bits:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explaination. 
I will leave percentages out of this, it seems to work just fine right now.
Eventually when I get better at C# I can come look at it again.
I tried the loop thingy and it seems to be good. As you have noticied this is a kind of lottery, so it must be easy to get 0 $ but harder to get 25 $, or 75 $, or 150 $ etc and it seems to do a fine job on that. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, but I just remembered another question. As you can see there are two items with same amount (10 000). How will this work? Will the program auto randomly pick one of the two or the first one, or the last one? How can I best solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is already taken into the account. Just look at the if-else branchs and the additions. The last two one before the "oops", first adds a "range of items" +10000, and the second adds **another** +10000. Thus, in your "virtual straight line of items" you have two sections that are 10000 items long. If the RNG generates a number between 6800000 and 6809999 it will hit the #4, and if it generates a number between 6810000 and 6819999 this will hit the #5. If you do not "see" or "feel" it, try drawing the line of items on a paper and see how the indexes/numbers add up!

Comment: Thanks. Now I have something to work on and try to understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your code has an integer division bug.

In any case, you will want to look at: Inverse Transform Sampling.

Basically, it allows you to take a uniform random number (what most PRNGs give you) and transform it to a random sample from any distribution. To do this, you need to use the CDF of the target distribution.

References & useful pages:

- ["Multinomial distribution - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"  [en.wikipedia.org]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)
- ["Inverse transform sampling - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"  [en.wikipedia.org]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)
- [Google Search: 'randomly draw from a multinomial'](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=randomly+draw+from+a+multinomial&oq=randomly+draw+from+a+multinomial&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.28101.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.efrsh..0.0...1.hknnXtIjgtY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2a3410d56eca1659&biw=1680&bih=972)

[[CiteHistory Record](http://bit.ly/NyMMC0)]

Edited:
I actually meant the categorical distribution, not the multinomial distribution. These two distributions are often conflated (especially in my field), but the difference is important. The two distributions are equivalent only when the multinomial distribution is parameterized with n = 1 (ie. one trial).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in my app and will convert it to your problem below:
In pseudo code:

- Sum up all values (to get the total)
- Get a random value between 0 and the sum
- Loop through all items summing up all values until that item
- When reached the random number, that item is the one belonging to the value.

The class Items looks as follows (removed some unimportant lines and added remarks with //

```
public class Items : List<Item>
{
    public Items() 
    {
        Add(new Item( 0, 3000000)); 
        Add(new Item(25, 1500000)); 
        Add(new Item(50, 2000000));
        // etc
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a random item based on value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Item GetRandomItem()
    {
        var sum = this.Sum(item => item.Value);
        var randomValue = new Random().Next(sum);

        // Iterate through itemsuntil found.
        var found = false;
        var itemIndex = 0;
        var visitedValue = 0;
        while (!found)
        {
            var item = this[itemIndex];
            if ((visitedValue + item.Value ) > randomValue)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                itemIndex++;
                visitedValue += item.value;                
            }
        }

        return this[itemIndex];        
    }
```

The Item class is nothing more than a placeholder for the Name and Value.

It looks long, but it has some benefits:

- When a value change, the sum is automatically calculated.
- When adding an item, only one line need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

One divisor must be a double to prevent zeros from division. To calculate the probability you need to cumulate them up to 100% ( or 1 ):

```
//     Element     - Probability      - Cumulative Probability
//     Item100     10000 / 6820000       0.001466275659824
//     Item75      300000 / 6820000      0.0439882697947214 + 0.001466275659824
//     Item50      2000000 / 6820000     0.2932551319648094 + 0.0454545454545454
//     Item25      1500000 / 6820000     0.219941348973607  + 0.3387096774193548
const double Item100 = 0.001466275659824;
const double Item75 = 0.0454545454545454;
const double Item50 = 0.3387096774193548;
const double Item25 = 0.5586510263929618;

int getRandomItem(Random rnd)
{
    double value = rnd.NextDouble();
    if (value <= Item100)
    {
        // use one of both possible items (100 or 150)
        int which = rnd.Next(0, 2);
        return which == 0 ? 100 : 150;
    }
    else if (value <= Item75)
        return 75;
    else if (value <= Item50)
        return 50;
    else if (value <= Item25)
        return 25;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

How you would use it:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var items = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    items.Add(getRandomItem(rnd));
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
```

Note that i reuse the random instance. If i would create it in the loop, the "random value would lways be the same since it would be seeded with the same time.

Comment: I already tried something like this, the problem was that 25 never got displayed, instead 50 took over all the time.

Comment: @Jack: I assume that the reason for that behaviour was that you always used a new random instance in a loop. Random will be seeded with the current time. In a loop it will be always the same time, therefor you'll always get the same "random" value. This is the reason why i pass the random instance as parameter to the method. You should create the random instance outside of the loop and always reuse the same. Another option would be to make the random a member variable in the class.

Comment: @Jack: Edited my answer to demonstrate above, also changed the probabilities because they need to be cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do you. Maybe not the best example in the world, but it should suffice:

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get ; private set ; }
    public int    Amount { get ; private set ; }

    public Item( string name , int amount )
    {
        if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ) throw new ArgumentException("name") ;
        if ( amount < 0 ) throw new ArgumentException("amount") ;

        this.Name = name ;
        this.Amount = amount ;

        return ;
    }
}
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    Random rng   = new Random() ;
    Item[] items = { new Item( "item--0"  , 3000000 ) ,
                     new Item( "item-25"  , 1500000 ) ,
                     new Item( "item-50"  , 2000000 ) ,
                     new Item( "item-75"  ,  300000 ) ,
                     new Item( "item-100" ,   10000 ) ,
                     new Item( "item-150" ,   10000 ) ,
                    } ;
    int    total = items.Sum( x => x.Amount ) ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i )
    {
        int  r = rng.Next(0, total ) ; // get a random integer x such that 0 <= x < total
        int  n = 0 ;
        Item selected = null ;
        int  lo = 0 ;
        int  hi = 0 ;
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < items.Length ; ++j )
        {
            lo = n ;
            hi = n + items[j].Amount ;
            n  = hi ;

            if ( r < n )
            {
                selected = items[j] ;
                break ;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine( "iteration {0}. r is {1} <= {2} < {3}. Selected item is {4}" ,
            i ,
            lo ,
            r ,
            hi ,
            selected.Name
            ) ;


    }

    return;
}
```